# Importing from cousin module in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following structure:

- LICENSE.md
- README.md
- requirements.txt
- src

  - routes

    - route_a.py
    - __ init __.py
  - util

    - __ init __.py
    - db.py

And in db.py, I have something that looks like this:

```
import mysql.connector

def get_value():
    # Query database using mysql.connector
    return value

value = get_value()

def query_that_uses_value(value):
     # do stuff with value
     return value2
```

I want to be able to use `value` inside of `route_a.py` and also inside of other functions in `db.py`. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Your current approach should work. Do you have any problems with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what to put in the other modules to make it work. Also it looks a bit odd to have to put value = get_value() in the middle of a module.

Comment: Maybe, you can use `get_value()` in other modules. If you want to cache result of function you can use [lru_cahce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator for the function instead of storing value in the variable

Comment: If I called `get_value()` multiple times, then I would have to make multiple calls to the database, which I would like to avoid if possible. I'm not sure how that decorator would make the value accessible across modules.

Comment: Yes, I've wrote about  [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). It stores function's result in cache. So you hit the DB only once even if call it multiple times.

Comment: Ok I'll try it out thanks

Comment: lru_cache worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys   
sys.path.insert(0, "path")
```

that's how I did it.
the path is the folder u want to use I would choose the main folder so u have the same starting point for your imports.

in your case, the import would look like this

```
from util.dp.py import get_value
```

if you have this at the start of your programme that u want the function imported to

```
sys.path.insert(0,"path_to_src/src")
```

but path to src must be an absolut path beginning from your root folder

Answer (score 0):

In `route_a.py`, simply `import` the variable `value` (and other functions you need) from `..util.db`, which is a relative import that will reference `src/util/db.py`. Here's what the file `src/routes/route_a.py` should contain:

```py
from ..util.db import value, function1, function2
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with imports is to `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)` in your project root directory where there are `src`, `requirements.txt`, etc.

So in your terminal, run `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)` and all your imports should be consistent and start from `src`.

For example:
`from src.util.db import value`
`from src.routes.route_a import something`

Note that everytime you open a new terminal you should run `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)` cause this is not permanent. When your terminal disappears your `PYTHONPATH` should reset and that's a good thing and is best practice.

Also don't forget to run everything from `src`. Like: `python src/util/db.py`

If you follow this structure, I promise you will never have any import problems.